# Android - custom permission notice dialog

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, notice

How can I replace the system notice dialog of the system permission(e.g the GPS) with my own dialog ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can`t**..

This is android documentation for permissions:

> When your app calls requestPermissions(), the system shows a standard
>   dialog box to the user. Your app cannot configure or alter that dialog
>   box. If you need to provide any information or explanation to the
>   user, you should do that before you call requestPermissions(), as
>   described in "Explain why the app needs permissions".

More details about it :
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so I can't do it in any version of android ,right ?

Comment: Yep, on the new versions of android you can only controll when permission must be shown etc. live time permission, in the old version you must declare them into Manifest.

Comment: OK ,Thank you very much!